# Who is "Eurip." and where is this Greek extract from?

Tags: quote-source

> Eἰς τὸν λειμῶνα καθίσας,
> ἔδρεπεν ἕτερον ἐφ' ἑτέρῳ
> αἰρόμενος ἄγρευμ' ἀνθέων
> ἁδομένᾳ ψυχᾷ
>
> [Eurip. *frag.* 754.] *[sic]*
>
> ['He sat in the meadow and plucked with glad heart the spoil of the flowers, gathering them one by one.']

This is the page before the preface of *Palgrave's Golden Treasury*: Palgrave, Francis Turner.

What is this *Eurip.* mentioned in the text? I found the Greek text [here](https://github.com/jstutters/poegen/blob/master/palgrave.txt).

Comment: *Eurip.*? Might be Euripedes: http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674996250 https://archive.org/details/euripideanfragme00euriuoft

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Hypsipyle* is a [lost or fragmentary play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euripides#Lost_and_fragmentary_plays) written around 410 BC by the Greek playwright [Euripides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euripides). This particular fragment survived due to its being quoted in [Book IV of *Symposiacs*](https://archive.org/details/b24886105_0003/page/290/mode/2up) by the Greek/Roman biographer and essayist [Plutarch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutarch), who lived between AD 46 – AD 120:

> Now if nothing is by its own nature hard to be digested, but it is the quantity that disturbs and corrupts, I think we have still greater reason to forbear that variety with which Philo’s cook, as it were in opposition to his master’s practice, would draw us on to surfeits and diseases. For, by the different sorts of food and new ways of dressing, he still keeps up the unwearied appetite, and leads it from one dish to another, till tasting of every thing we take more than is sufficient and enough; as Hypsipyle’s foster-child,
>
> > Who, in a garden placed, plucked up the flowers,
> > One after one, and spent delightful hours;
> > But still his greedy appetite goes on,
> > And still he plucked till all the flowers were gone.
>
> <sub>Plutarch. [*Symposiacs*, book IV](https://archive.org/details/b24886105_0003/page/290/mode/2up). Translated by William Watson Goodwin (1870). *Plutarch’s Morals*, p. 291. London: Sampson Low, son, and Marston.</sub>

So this is likely a fragment of *Hypsipyle* that we only know about because Plutarch quoted it in his book ~500 years after the play was written.